# Replace sequences of two or more underscores or double quotes with a single underscore

Tags: php, string, function, recursion, replace

I'm trying to develope a recursive function I can use to strip a string of instances of multiple values.

This is what I have so far:

```
$words = 'one__two_"__three';

$words = stripall(array('__', '"'), '_', $words);

echo $words;

function stripall($values, $replace, $string) {
            
    foreach ($values as $value) {
        
        if (strpos($string, $value)) {
            
            $string = str_replace($value, $replace, $string);
            
            stripall($values, $replace, $string);
        }
    }
    
    return $string;
}
```

Here the $words string is getting stripped of all instances of two underscores (__) or a quote ("). Or at least in theory...

The target return value being:

```
one_two_three
```

However, what I am getting is "one_two___three"

Comment: Its becuase there is an `_`  followed by a `"`  which after filtering becomes a `_`  and then there is a `__` which is changed into a `_`  resulting in a `__`  -- just add change the `stripall($values, $replace, $string);`  inside of your function  to:  `return  stripall($values, $replace, $string);`   and it will work

Answer (score 2):

```
$words = 'one__two_"__three';
$words = stripall(array('"','__'), '_', $words);
echo $words;
function stripall($values, $replace, $string) {
    foreach ($values as $value) {
        while (strpos($string, $value)) {
            $string = str_replace($value, $replace, $string);
            stripall($values, $replace, $string);
        }
    }
    return $string;
}
```

Changed the IF to While and first remove " and then check for __

Comment: `while(strpos(...))` can evaluate to `while(0)` which will exit the loop, and shouldn't. The [strpos docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) explicitly says to test using `=== false`

Answer (score 1):

I'm kind of confused on your expected output:

```
one_two_three
```

Assuming your string:

```
$words = 'one__two_"__three';
```

And your rules:

> Here the $words string is getting
> stripped of all instances of two
> underscores (__) or a quote (")

We would strip the string like this:

```
$words = 'one[__]two_["][__]three';
```

So your expected output should be:

```
onetwo_three
```

Which by using the array form of [str_replace](https://www.php.net/str_replace):

```
$words = 'one__two_"__three';
echo str_replace(array('"', "__"), "", $words) . "\n";
```

I get exactly that output:

```
$ php test.php
onetwo_three
```

Comment: possibly he means to replace all `"__"` with `"_"`?

Comment: Yes, Jaitsu got it.  I'm trying to replace all doube underscores with singles.  I could potentially have a string with several underscores, and I want all consecutive ones to be replaced with a single.

And onteria, if I run what you did, I get "one_two___three" (note the triple underscores)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think anyone could possibly convince me to use a loop or non-regex approach for this one.  If anyone would not use regex, I would assume that they simply don't understand the power and utility of performing replacements on varying character sequences.

The pattern merely sweeps through the input string(s) and replaces all sequences of one or more underscores and/or double quotes.

The only unnecessary side effect of this technique (but it doesn't negatively affect the outcome) is that it will needlessly replace a single underscore with a single underscore. Ideally patterns should not be designed to do needless matches/replacements, but in this case it spare the requirement to make a second sweep through the string(s) to clean up any newly generated consecutive underscores.

This perfectly tidies up your text with just one function call -- this is exactly why regex exists.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/pWCXt))

```
$strings = [
    'one"two_"_"_three',
    'one__two_"__three',
    'one__two_"__""____"three',
    'one__two___"""""""______three',
];

var_export(
    preg_replace('~["_]+~', '_', $strings)
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'one_two_three',
  1 => 'one_two_three',
  2 => 'one_two_three',
  3 => 'one_two_three',
)
```

Comment: I didn't dv but I would only consider `preg*` a _"lean"_ solution if by lean you mean _"lean on"_, like a crutch. Fwiw your array of expressions can be simplified to a single expression, which doesn't depend on order when applied: `preg_replace('/["_]+/', '_', $strings)`

Comment: I am calling it "lean" because it is direct in its execution.  I agree with your pattern suggestion, clearly I was _over-thinking it, so I'll updated my answer.  Cheers @Tha  Fortunately, my attacker has moved on from my answers and is now executing a very deliberate/controlled daily DV on my questions -- and I don't have many questions to attack :).

Comment: SO is pretty good about detecting so-called [_serial down-voting_](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/what-can-i-do-if-im-the-victim-of-serial-downvoting). I am curious about your understanding of `preg*` though because their use is anything but _direct_. There's an entire grammar, lexer, parser, and evaluator to support regular expression operations. From a beginner's perspective, the regex "engine" is a magic hat where funny-looking strings go in and the answer mysteriously pop out. It's hard to debug unless you have intimate knowledge of the grammar and features.

Comment: I am very confortable with regex, so I don't consider it to be magic.  I consider it to be very appropriate in this case.  If you don't think a single preg_ call is direct, then I fear you have a bais against regex. It has been my experience that SO poorly detects serial voting and then when it does, it just returns the points to the offender, then they learn to pace their attacks out so that SO scripts don't detect it.  The impact in this case, is not merely the DV on my post, but the UV on the other posts (which I would not endorse) -- all in a ploy to steer researchers away from my advice.

Answer (score 0):

Would you like to try mine?

```
//Example:
/*
    $data = strReplaceArrayRecursive(
        array('{name}'=>'Peter','{profileImg}'=>'./PRF-AAD036-51dc30ddc4.jpg'),
        array(
            'title'=>'My name is {name}',
            'post'=>array(
                'author' => '{name}',
                'image' => '{profileImg}',
                'content' => 'My post.'
            )
        )
    );
    print_r($data);
//Expect:
Array
(
    [title] => My name is Peter
    [post] => Array
        (
            [author] => Peter
            [image] => ./PRF-AAD036-51dc30ddc4.jpg
            [content] => My post.
        )

)
*/
function strReplaceArrayRecursive($replacement=array(),$strArray=false,$isReplaceKey=false){
    if (!is_array($strArray)) {
        return str_replace(array_keys($replacement), array_values($replacement), $strArray);
    }
    else {
        $newArr = array();
        foreach ($strArray as $key=>$value) {
            $replacedKey = $key;
            if ($isReplaceKey) {
                $replacedKey = str_replace(array_keys($replacement), array_values($replacement), $key);
            }
            $newArr[$replacedKey] = strReplaceArrayRecursive($replacement, $value, $isReplaceKey);
        }
        return $newArr;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

This function is entirely unnecessary. `str_replace` already does the same thing.

Comment: False.  If I run it that way I still get a result of "one_two___three" with triple underscores.

Comment: you can use  preg_replace_callback instead of str_replace

Comment: There is no valid reason to use `preg_replace_callback()` for this task.